# Crop large GeoJson layer using a standard machine

Tags: crop, large-data, qgis, vector-graphics

I need to extract a portion of a large GeoJson layer. I've tried multiple times with QGis on a 16Gb Ram intel i7 11th gen processor with no result. After about one hour if the program does not crash, I am able to load the file in QGis but no way of cropping it using the Clip vector function.

The layer in question is publicly available at https://github.com/microsoft/KenyaNigeriaBuildingFootprints (the file is kenya.geojson.zip)
... and the extent I need is 36.753446978,36.821255765,-1.330521423,-1.295234032 [EPSG:4326]

Comment: Geojson is not a raster

Comment: You are right, let me update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can approach that with R.

Get the data

```
options(timeout=max(6000, getOption("timeout")))
url <- "https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/africa/kenya.geojsonl.zip"
download.file(url, basename(url), mode="wb")
f <- unzip("kenya.geojsonl.zip")
f 
#"./kenya.geojsonl"
```

Read a subset by specifying an extent. This takes a while because geojson is a rather inefficient format.

```
library(terra)
e <- ext(36.753446978, 36.821255765, -1.330521423, -1.295234032)

## with timer
system.time(v <- vect("kenya.geojsonl", extent=e))
#   user  system elapsed 
#1390.03    8.28 1409.11 

v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 18159, 0  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 36.75303, 36.8228, -1.331356, -1.29447  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : kenya.geojsonl
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

And then perhaps:

```
writeVector(v, "buildings.shp")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this during the weekend or on Monday, and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: It looks like you did run the code with the actual data. May I ask you how long did this take? Did you use a standard PC for the task?

Comment: You can see *exactly* what I did and the result as well. I used my laptop. I did not time it but I think it took 15 minutes or so.

Comment: I have added a timer. It took about 23 minutes on a pretty good laptop

Comment: It worked, Thanks! I run the code from my home machine (a Surface Go tablet). Even this weak machine managed to do the job (in about less than a hour).